# Changing CellColor in MS Project 2016 with c#

Tags: c#, add-in, ms-project

I am currently making a MS Project 2016 Add-In and I need to color specific task ( row of the task ), when a condition is true.
I am using c# .NET4

I made a method:

```
public void colorYellow(MSProject.Task task){
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.SelectRow(task.ID);
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.CellColor = PjColor.pjYellow;      
    }
```

I am getting exception: Unexpected method error.

Is there a way how to color whole task row somehow? 
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: With line 1 being the function prototype, on what line does the error occur if you step through with the debugger? It should be possible to do what you want: hang in there.

Answer (score 0):

The Unexpected method error comes from the fact that you are actually selecting a blank row because the `SelectRow` method is ***relative*** by default. Unless the optional, second argument `RowRelative` is passed in as False, the selection moves `task.ID` rows forward. So try:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.SelectRow(task.ID, false);
```

[See MSDN reference for the SelectRow method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-selectrow-method-project)

If the cell color is still not changing, look at the [Font32Ex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-font32ex-method-project) method for an alternative way to change the cell color. Despite the MSDN reference indicating the Color argument changes the *font* color, several SO posts (and my own testing) show that it actually changes the background color. (Note: this is far from the only case where the MSDN reference page for MS Project is not accurate.)

[SO post #1 about changing background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154574/changing-background-row-color-according-to-task-levels-in-ms-project-vba)

[SO post #2 about color coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951578/color-coding-tasks-in-a-microsoft-project-macro)

(Note on code sample: I am a vb.net programmer... not sure if that's the correct syntax for passing False as the second argument.)